# Looping back to an intent without repeat the responses list

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to do something similar to this question: [Looping back to an intent?](https://discuss.api.ai/t/looping-back-to-an-intent/9759)

My bot is telling jokes when a user ask "Tell me a joke", (intent: `smalltalk.agent.telljoke`) and if the user respond with "another one" I want to send another one.

I understand the answer in the linked question, I can create `repeat.smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent if the user say "another one" with a specific input context set in `smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent.

But can I trigger my `smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent in the `repeat.smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent ? I am not calling a webhook to get the jokes **so they are in the Responses section of my `smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent** and I do not want to write them at two places (in both intents).

Can I redirect an intent to another one's responses ?

I asked the same question on the Dialogflow Google forum: 
[Looping back to an intent without repeat the responses list](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/dialogflow/PFQdKHj7CsI;context-place=forum/dialogflow)

Answer (score 0):

To have the input "another one" trigger the joke-telling intent (`smalltalk.agent.telljoke`), just add "another one" to the training phrases of that intent. There's no need to have two intents if they both do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Yes but the phrase "another one" could be something else if it is not after `smalltalk.agent.telljoke`

Comment: what if there are multiple Intents that wants this "another one" feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adding an output context (let's name it `anotherJoke`) to your `smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent which can expire after two messages (to allow a follow up to a `ha ha ha` or `lol` from the user).

Then create a new intent (maybe `smalltalk.agent.anotherJoke`) that will take the `anotherJoke` as it's input context.Make this intent recognize `another one`, `shoot again`, etc and provide another set of jokes for it.

That way the `smalltalk.agent.anotherJoke` intent will have priority matching only after the `smalltalk.agent.telljoke` intent has been triggered, the context kinda links the two intents together.

Comment: "and provide another set of jokes for it" I want to use the same set in the two intents

Comment: I know is not too maintainable, but you can just copy the intent along with the responses (jokes) to generate that follow up intent

Comment: Dialogflow does not care maintenability too much, that's for sure